# Want to access microservice using microservice name without port number using eureka server

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

When I am try to access microservice using eureka server webclient builder asking for microservicename along with no-standard port number.  If I am not use port number it is generating error.

I want to use eureka server for service discovery. My idea is when you discovering a microservice you need not to mention non-standerd port address along with microservice name . But in my case I have to mention port address Here is my all code details :

eureka server :

application.properties:

```java
    spring.application.name=eureka-server
    server.port=8761

    eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
    eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
```

code spring boot :

```java
    @SpringBootApplication
    @EnableEurekaServer
    public class EurakaServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(EurakaServerApplication.class, args);
    }

    }
```

consumerservice:

```java
     @Service

public class ConsumerService {

    @LoadBalanced
    private final WebClient webClient;

    public ConsumerService(WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder) {
        this.webClient = webClientBuilder.baseUrl("http://microservice1:8080").build();
    }


    public Mono<String> getProcessedData() {
        return webClient
                .get()
                .uri("/producer/data")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
                .map(data -> data + " - Extra Information Added");
       }
    }
```

Consumer Controller:

```java
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/consumer")
    public class ConsumerController {

    private final ConsumerService consumerService;


    public ConsumerController(ConsumerService consumerService) {
        this.consumerService = consumerService;
    }
    //localhost:8081/consumer/processed-data
    @GetMapping("/processed-data")
    public Mono<String> getProcessedData() {
        return consumerService.getProcessedData();
    }
    }
```

application.properties:

```
    server.port=8081
    spring.application.name=microservice2
```

Producer application.properties:

```
    server.port=8080
    spring.application.name=microservice1
```

ProducerApplication :

```java
    @SpringBootApplication
    @EnableDiscoveryClient
    public class ProducerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(ProducerApplication.class, args);
    }}
```

The error message(if I remove port number 8080):

```bash
Servlet.service() for servlet \[dispatcherServlet\] in context with path \[\] threw exception \[Request processing failed: org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused: microservice1/127.0.0.1:80\] with root cause

java.net.ConnectException: finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused
```

I don't want to use microservice1:8080(for me it is working). I want to use only "microservice1".If I am not mentioning port 8080 the it automatically looking for port 80. It showing connection refuse error. I want to use http://microservice1 .

Thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create your own configuration class and create a builder for your service by giving the `baseUrl` without the port (only server name) like this.

```java
@Configuration
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UtilConfigWebClient {

    private final EurekaClient eurekaClient;

    /**
     * this is only for microservice1
     *
     * @return {@link WebClient.Builder} with base url as http://microservice1
     */
    @Bean("microservice1WebClientBuilder")
    @LoadBalanced
    public WebClient.Builder paymentWebClientBuilder() {
        return WebClient.builder()
                .baseUrl("http://microservice1");
    }
}
```

Inject that bean (It should be the WebClient.Builder. Not a WebClient) in your ConsumerService service by using `@Qualifier` Like this.

```java
@Service
public class ConsumerService {
    private final WebClient.Builder microservice1WebClient;

    public ConsumerService(@Qualifier("microservice1WebClientBuilder") WebClient.Builder microservice1WebClient) {
        this.microservice1WebClient = microservice1WebClient;
    }

    public Mono<String> getProcessedData() {
        return microservice1WebClient.build()
                .get()
                .uri("/producer/data")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
                .map(data -> data + " - Extra Information Added");
    }
}
```